# Cannot install numpy in Cygwin even after installing python-devel

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pip, cygwin

I have tried multiple times deleting my `cygwin64` folder and reinstalling cygwin with `python37` and `python37-devel` and trying to run

`pip3 install numpy==1.21.6`

but I keep getting the message

`SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.`

What could be the issue? I already have the python development package for the version of python I installed, so this is quite frustrating. I also tried with `python39` and `python39-devel`, got the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I just switched to Windows Subsystem for Linux and my life became a lot easier.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It was also easy to check available packages

https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/python-numpy-src.html

Numpy 1.21.4-1 was already available as

python39-numpy
python38-numpy
..

Comment: Unfortunately, I require other packages than just numpy and ran into problems installing them even after installing python39-numpy.
I installed python39, python39-devel, python39-numpy, and gcc-core. I attempted to run `pip3 install scikit-learn` and `pip3 install pandas` and both failed. Moreover, it took 35 minutes to build the wheel for the pandas installation, which is a bit ridiculous.

Comment: scikit-learn error:
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-givsmo0f/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 148, in __init__
                      self.cmake_version = get_cmake_version(self.cmake_executable)
                    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-givsmo0f/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 105, in get_cmake_version
                      raise SKBuildError(msg) from err

                  Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is cmake
                  [end of output]

Comment: pandas error (the full output was 2500 lines so this is just a small snippet):
=0 -Ipandas/_libs/window -I/tmp/pip-build-env-o22yujgs/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c pandas/_libs/window/aggregations.cpp -o build/temp.cygwin-3.4.6-x86_64-cpython-39/pandas/_libs/window/aggregations.o
      gcc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1plus’: spawn: No such file or directory
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]